# How to insert into postgre database without concatenate strings?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

My code is like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO oraculo VALUES(".$name.$pass.")";
    pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
```

In java i use PreparedStament to insert values without concatenate strings (to avoid sql injection if im right). Is possible to do something like this in PHP? Im want to do something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO oraculo VALUES(?, ?)";
//set the value of first '?'
setValue(1, "somename");
//set the value of second '?'
setValue(2, "somepass");
pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
```

Comment: [Read](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). [The](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php). [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Though in fairness PHP's documentation is pretty dire - the docs for pg_query should have huge loud warnings pointing to those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pg_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) to execute prepared statements to postgres in PHP.

So your code would look like:

```
pg_prepare($dbconn, "login", 'SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name = $1');
$rs = pg_execute($dbconn, "login", array("somename", "somepass"));
```

Comment: Or use `pg_query_params`. Or, y'know, PDO, which has replaced the deprecated mysqli and pg drivers for 10 years now...

Comment: @CraigRinger sorry to say -- I know you are not a PHP dev ;) -- PDO has not deprecated the pg_* drivers. It proposes a common interface for all drivers at the expense of performances and some features. PHP’s pg_* are still maintained and have new features over time. Those should be preferred if you know your project will use PostgreSQL only.

Comment: @greg OK, thanks, good to know. I was under the impression from docs and discussion that PDO was intended to replace the individual drivers, rather than wrap them. Sorry for the confusion. I stand  by my comments that the PHP docs are shockingly lax in failing to offer a GIANT WARNING on the pg_query page that points to http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php . It says "pg_query_params() should be preferred in most cases." but that's clearly way too weak a statement given these kinds of questions.